# Check server operation status in C#. Check state of server process (business operation)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-state

Client application initiates a process on a server (via RIA, but the implementationis not important).  When I say process, I mean business code running and not referring to an actual process running on the CPU.

Code is C#.

The client then checks to see the process status. Failed, completed, still running.

The basics are relatively easy to implement. I store a process Id statically on the server in which the client can poll the server regularily to check the process which will check the status associated with the process id.

Edge cases around this require a bit more work. Fatal and catastrophic reasons that abnormally abort the thread (process) without allowing the code to handle the exception and gracefully set the status associated with the process to fail.  In this scenario, the client will continue to assume the process is still in progress.

I was thinking of running the process in a separate thread andf tracking the thread id.  When the client calls the server to check process state, we could check the IsAlive property of the thread running the process.

I am wondering if there are any scenarios where this could be problematic? Maybe there could be a chance that IsAlive would return True although the thread is hung.

Another approach would be to have the process on the server periodically set a timestamp which could be used when the client checks the state.  The code checking the state, could see how old the timestamp is and then based on whatever interval we chose (let's say 2 minutes) it could decide if the process is still running (2 minutes hasn't passed since last timestamp written), or process has timedout without exception (more than 2 minutes has passed since the thread wrote the last timestamp). All timestamps would be done in memory.

Are there any best practices surrounding this that could be beneficial?  Does anyone have any special insight or tips on how to best approach this? I am also open to other scenarios or ideas people have?

Comment: Also, please note that this is generally a long running operation with many code steps.  Server process could take an hour or more to complete.

Comment: You can made a parallel with messaging systems [Keep Alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) term, so each running business process (BP) is aware of sending its KeepAlive message indicating its running state. To avoid high network load you can send KA messages to local listener which would collect statistics, scenario with timestamp you've provided shoudl work pretty well as long as listener is a separate process, but you should think how to cover cases when listener hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the better approach is to have a fully controled server app which handles everything including exceptions for each business process and maintains state of all. and the even better if client receives StateChanged event rather than polling (with WCF duplex channels for example). what you do is 1999 basically. .NET gives you all the stuff almost for free. correct architecture actually faster to write and in time cheaper to support.